# Regex to extract string not included in double quotes

Tags: regex, r, pcre

E.g., I need to get everything outside double quotes:

```
This is a string outside quotes, and "these words are in quotes" which I want to ignore.
```

The result should be:

```
This is a string outside quotes, and  which I want to ignore.
```

After many searches I found very similar one like:
http://www.rubular.com/r/kxm0cEx8gD

But it doesn't give me desired result.

What I managed to achieve so far is:

```
(.?(?!["]))((?<!["]).?)

    (.?(?!["])) - negative lookahead - I expect to give me all symbols before the ["]

    ((?<!["]).?) - negative lookbehind - I expect to give all the symbols not preceded by ["]
```

I'm using R which supports perl syntax and PCRE 8.0

Comment: I m using R which supports perl syntax and PCRE 8.0

Comment: will you ever have nested quotes?

Comment: @hwnd you surely mean *escaped* quotes, right?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski, `"foo "and bar" not baz but "quz" ..."`

Comment: @hwnd oh I see... I hope no one has to deal with such text too much :-)

Comment: Please tag your questions properly. Don't just lump irrelevant tags into your question - that just defeats the purpose of tags altogether. You may argue that [perl] was relevant because of PCRE, but [javascript] is flat-out irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

You could try

```
sub('"[^"]*"', '', str1)
#[1] "This is a string outside quotes, and  which I want to ignore."
```

**NOTE:** If there are multiple instances, use `gsub` instead of `sub`

```
gsub('"[^"]*"', '', str2)
#[1] "This is a string outside quotes, and  which I want to ignore. and  thank you"
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- 'This is a string outside quotes, and "these words are in quotes" which I want to ignore.'

 str2 <- 'This is a string outside quotes, and "these words are in quotes" which I want to ignore. and "these words" thank you'
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic of `"[^"]+"`

Comment: Thank you, @akrun. Is there a way to do it through the:

str1<-paste ("This is a string outside quotes, and \"these words are in quotes\" which I want to ignore."); 
r<-regexpr('"[^"]+"', str1); 
x<-regmatches(str1, r). So to avoid replacement.

Comment: It matches an initial double quote, `[^ ... ]` is a negated character class, the caret `^` inside (negation operator) means match everything **NOT**, so the class matches everything that is not a double quote, followed by the ending quote.

Comment: @dimitris_ps We match `"` followed by all characters except `"` ie. `[^"]` followed by `"` and replace it with `''`

Comment: Thanks,  @akrun i didn't know about `^` in brackets, i thought it was `starts with`.

Comment: @dimitris_ps If it is outside the `[`, it had a different meaning.

Comment: The question was how to get everything outside double quotes while the regex '"[^"]*"' does exactly the opposite and is more a workaround rather than a solution.

Comment: @Alex I was removing everything inside the double quotes to get the expected output.  It is one way of getting the expected output.  If you can show an example where it doesn't work, I can look into it.

Comment: Thank you, @akrun, your approach works good. Although I m looking for regex which will return me everything without replacement since I need to keep the original text and don't want to create duplicated var with replaced text.

Comment: @Alex I think you are looking for `regmatches/str_extract` approach.  I don't know if that is easier to code.

Answer (score 2):

You can delete the quoted parts of the string using `s/"[^"]*"//g`. Or if you don't want to modify the original string then you can use the non-destructive modifier `/r`, which has been available since version 14 of Perl 5

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.014;

my $ss = 'This is a string outside quotes, and "these words are in quotes" which I want to ignore.';

say $ss =~ s/"[^"]*"//gr;
```

**output**

```
This is a string outside quotes, and  which I want to ignore.
```

Answer (score 1):

The `rm_between` function from the **qdapRegex** package that I maintain is a general solution to the sort of problem where you have the remove or extract content between a left and right boundary:

```
x <- c(
    'This is a string outside quotes, and "these words are in quotes" which I want to ignore.',
    'A second sentence "delete me" and also "delete me"'
)

library(qdapRegex)
rm_between(x, "\"", "\"")

## [1] "This is a string outside quotes, and which I want to ignore."
## [2] "A second sentence and also"
```

To look at the regular expression used:

```
S("@rm_between", "\"")
## [1] "(\")(.*?)(\")"
```

Comment: Thank you, @Tyler, nice package. Seems like function rm_between removes everything between double quotes. I didn't find any function which gives me everything not bounded in quotes though.

Comment: What's the diffetence?  The output is the same is it not?

Comment: As I said in one of my comments above, I need to keep original text and there don't want to create duplicated var with replaced text 'cos of extra resources (RAM, CPU) allocation.

Comment: With any approach you either have to modify in place or create a copy if you want to see/work with the output.